# How to customize scrolling for any action that moves the point?

Tags: motion, scrolling

Say I have an action that moves the point (adds 100 to it for example).

It should be possible to wrap this with a function or macro that gives additional behavior, eg:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>")
  'move-point-plus-100)
```

Say I want to animate the motion with smooth scrolling and recenter the view. This should be possible using a macro, for example.

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>")
  (with-fancy-scroll-motion 'move-point-plus-100))
```

Then I can separate scrolling behavior from the actions that move the point, allowing for separate configuration & control.

Does something like this exist already? Or would it need to be written?

---

- I'm aware of scroll locking & smooth scroll mode, but I'd rather have the ability to apply this per key binding, then adding a global mode which might run when I don't want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any existing packages that did this, I wrote my own: [scroll-on-jump](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-scroll-on-jump).

This defines macros and utilities to advise existing functions to have customized scrolling behavior on jump.

[See demo video](https://www.reddit.com/link/j43uhj/video/3mxv64594tq51/player).